# React-Native ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Error (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native, build.gradle

Recently dove into the world of React-Native and got roadblocked immediately. Bought a course from Udemy called The Complete React Native and Redux Course and got stuck trying to compile my first application.

I've tried a bunch of different solutions and have gone through a variety of different errors so its come to the point where I have to make my first stackoverflow post. Going to post a bunch of my current settings below as well as the error im receiving.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFkn0.png)

***My Configuations***

[Java SDK/JRE's I have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwzDj.png)

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

PATH = C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Roaming\npm;

***React Native Properties***

[React-Native Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0QmH.png)

***Android Studio Properties***

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC0YL.png)

[SDK/JDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0JTh.png)

[Installed SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdmMp.png)

[Installed SDK's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgz7B.png)

*gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
#Mon Dec 11 21:41:46 EST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-rc-2-
all.zip
```

*build.gradle (Module:app)*

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.albums"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

*build.gradle (Project: albums)*

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
mavenLocal()
jcenter()
}
```

}

In the course im using the instructor says to use the NEXUS 5 API 23, incase that helps. Gradle builds within Android Studio no errors.

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Did u create your project using `react-native init albums` command?

Comment: hey yes i did, followed instructor commands for that @ravi

Comment: Visit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html and select 'Building projects with native code'  --> 'windows' (Development OS) ---> 'android' (Target OS). Check if you have done all the installation properly for development. And try to create a new project.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ravi, I just recreated it and compiled it successfully. I think all the changing of configurations messed it up. All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Deleted my project, recreated it with react-native init ProjectName, ran AVD, compiled project through terminal. I think I altered too many configurations in my old one and needed to recreate it.